# Is a RESTful url valid without ids between objects?

Tags: restful-url

I have two RESTful API design questions.  Let's say I have a fruitstand web app.  I want to return information about all the fruits I carry and the counts those fruits, and I do it with:

```
http://myfruitstand.com/fruits
```

**Question 1:**
If I have 10 oranges, then I'm thinking that I can get information about a particular orange with:

```
http://myfruitstand.com/fruits/oranges/3
```

But is the above url RESTful--don't I need an id between 'fruits' and 'oranges' to conform to REST standards?  Or is this url with 'fruits' being immediately followed with the subclass 'oranges' okay?

**Question 2:**
Similarly, if I want to have a discussion forum about my oranges (not a particular orange), can I put it here:

```
http://myfruitstand.com/fruits/oranges/comments
```

Again, is the above url RESTful since there's no id between 'oranges' and 'comments' (an id here, of course, would imply a discussion about a particular orange and I don't want that)?  Here, there's no subclass rational of 'oranges' being immediately followed by 'comments.'

thanks in advance, Chuck

Answer (score 1):

It would be more RESTful to construct by resource-collection/id pairs, e.g. /fruits/:id1/items/:id2, where id1 = orange, id2 = 3

```
/fruits/orange/items/3
```

Then the answer to the second question would be also correct if you lose the 's' on oranges, as you are treating orange as an instance of a resource and not a resource collection.

```
/fruits/orange/comments
```

e.g. slide 48 of http://www.slideshare.net/Wombert/phpnw10-designing-http-services-and-restful-interfaces

Comment: So I guess that's the $64 question--whether to treat orange as a resource or a type.  Arghhh....I've run into this issue on multiple fronts, and it seems to come to a head when exposing my model via REST...  Thanks, Andy

Comment: The way I would see it is if there are resources associated with an entity, it is an item of a parent resource rather than a collection. I'll just update the wording to make it less ambiguous what I'm meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Just been asking questions about RESTful style myself. But my take on this is:

If it's a fruit store, isn't 'fruit' implied? How about simply:

/oranges/{id}

Alternatively:

/fruits/{id}

Which is just a fruit of type Orange.

/fruits?type=orange could return you a list of oranges

Answer (score 0):

Yes all urls are restful as long as they are deterministic. Restful is more about the http-methods you are using (DELETE for instance to delete, POST to edit, GET to read, ...).

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't believe from your explanation of usage that you need an id for the fruit resource.
2. Similarly no id needed for the second one either.

As long as your urls model your object organization then I believe you're good to go.

Also, my personal feeling is that if you find a case where  you need to depart ever so slightly from any specification to meet your application needs, that's a reasonable thing to do. Do not allow adherence to this sort of 'model' interfere with getting the job done. For example in the RESTful context, sometimes you perform actions related to some objects that just don't fall clearly under the DELETE/PUT/POST/GET verbs. Do you smoosh those things into there in order to maintain perfect RESTfulness?

I am now hiding behind my desk so as not to be knocked unconscious by the RESTful gurus/religionists that will inevitably beat up on me now :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and I won't tell the extremists under which desk you are hiding :-)